# Why the compiler doesn't simply move data from edi to eax in unoptimized debug builds?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I was observing the assembly created for the following function [here](https://godbolt.org/z/7Y8dMT8Wc).

```c
int square(int num) {
    return num;
}
```

This is the assembly generated for the function above:

```
square:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

My question is, can I rewrite it into this and assume that it works fine?

```
square:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, edi
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

What is the need to first move `edi` into `[rbp-4]` and then move `[rbp-4]` into `eax`? Since both source and destination are registers I think we can move data in a single move instruction.

### Edited

My question is about unoptimized version of code, I know if I compile it with `-O1` it emits far more short and succinct code. But my question is about semantics of that extra `mov` instruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without optimization, the compiler generates the steps to do following a literal specification of the language. In C, the parameters to a function are essentially local variables, much as if you had declared them inside the function. So this C code:

```
int square(int num)
{
    …
}
```

is, in the semantics of the C standard, much like:

```
int square(?)
{
    int num = value that the caller passed as the first argument;
    …
}
```

Without optimization, the compiler is following this model. When the routine starts, the compiler sets up a stack frame and stores the arguments (which are in registers) to the parameters (which are on the stack).

Then `return num;` loads the parameter from the stack.

With optimization on, the compiler removes the unnecessary use of the stack.

Comment: It spills them to the stack because ISO C says every variable has an address, and at `-O` compilers don't optimize between statements for consistent debugging: *[Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394)*.  Except for `register int num`; you can't take its address so GCC/clang `-O0` builds will keep `register` vars in registers. `int square(register int num) { return num; }`.  But don't do that because it makes no difference otherwise and is distracting for readers.

Comment: Correction, only GCC keeps `register` vars in registers in `-O0` anti-optimized debug builds, clang doesn't. https://godbolt.org/z/f68c4a6qx .  (Fun fact: C++ deprecated and then removed the `register` keyword, but it seems to be alive and well in C23, at least no warnings from GCC or clang.  Not that I'd recommend it, though, unless you need to optimize a debug build, e.g. of a game or other real-time program that can only be debugged properly if it runs fast enough...)

Answer (score 2):

Trust your compiler's optimizer.

If you compile with `-O1`, you end up with the following:

```
square:
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is that why the unoptimized version do that thing. Other things such as `push rbp` and `mov rbp, rsp` seems reasonable to me. But I can't understand the logic behind that `mov` instruction.

Comment: @Amir reza Riahi, What do you mean? The logic is extremely simple. It stores the value somewhere to be used later. And later, it reads the value it stores. It's very straightforward. Unless you're asking why it's inefficient, and both you dbush and Amir reza Riahi already answered that: The code hasn't been optimized.

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi, but you failed to actually ask about unoptimized, making no reference to unoptimized until this comment.

Comment: @ErikEidt You're right, I'll edit my question.

Comment: @ikegami What's inside the `edi` that it is moving it into the memory?

Comment: @Amir reza Riahi, The argument, the value for `num`.

Comment: @ikegami, shouldn't arguments be placed on the stack by the convention? especially when this is an unoptimized version of generated assembly.

Comment: Re "*shouldn't arguments be placed on the stack by the convention?*", I just said the argument is in `edi`.

Answer (score 1):

The best compiler technology we have is to generate stupid, simple, accurate code, and then use pattern recognition, repeated over and over, to optimize that.

This approach catches many opportunities for optimization, ones that would be hidden from a "smart" compiler that would generate better code in the first place.  So, yes, a compiler could generate better non-optimizing code, but the effort of decades of research says that the pattern recognition is where the investment should go.

Further, simple accurate code generated initially unoptimized is friendly toward debugging, which is actually pretty complicated if you start applying too many smarts to the initially generated code.

So, the priorities are: generate code that is accurate in execution and in  debugging, then, when requested, use various kinds of pattern matching to identify and perform optimizing transformations, repeatedly.

Comment: Well, I totally understand it, my question was about semantics and meaning of that `mov` instruction. As an example, in my case we could remove `push ebp; mov ebp, esp` and everything works fine, and I have no question about why the compiler have generated those instructions, because I know the semantics of those instructions. But I didn't know meaning of that `mov` instruction. I have no problem that the code is not optimized, I just did not understand the purpose of some part of it.

Comment: Unlike registers, stack memory survives computations and function calls, so it is the preferred location for variables by the naïve code generator, one that doesn't look at the rest of the function for optimization.